# Bifurcation of the dde $x'(t) = r x(t-d) - h x(t)$ wich describes a population model with delay

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bifurcation, delay-differential-equations

Consider the following population model: $x'(t) = r x(t-d) - h x(t)$, with growth rate $r > 0$ and death rate $h > 0$, where only adults that have reached the age $d > 0$ can reproduce.

I have to draw a bifurcation diagram. For $d = 0$ it looks easy but I don't know how to do it for $d > 0$ since it's my first encounter with a DDE. Can someone help me?

**My approach:**

The first thing to do would be to rescale the time so the delay becomes 1 and have all parameters outside $x$. we can take $a = \frac{t}{d}$, it'll probably look something like this: $\frac{1}{d}x′(a) = ... - h y(a)$, where $y(a) = x(t)$.
I don't know how the term $r x(t-d)$ should look.
I can also assume we seek solutions of the form $ce^{\lambda t}$, so I can derive the characteristic function.

Comment: Could you say why you have to do this and what you have done so far or what your thoughts were behind it? So that we can really help you. Otherwise it's just a question of the form "[That's my task. ... Please solve the problem.]" and that doesn't meet the standards on Math.SE.

Comment: The first thing to do would be to rescale the time so the delay becomes 1 and have all parameters outside x. we can take $a = \frac{t}{d}$, it'll probably look something like this: $\frac{1}{d} \dot x'(a) = ... - hy(a)$, where $y(a) = x(t)$. I don't know how the term $rx(t-d)$ should look. I can also assume we seek solutions of the form $ce^{\lambda t}$, so I can derive the characteristic function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, your problem is solving the DDE. To do this you can simply substitute $x\left( t \right) = e^{\lambda \cdot t}$ (aka $x'\left( t \right) = \lambda \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot t}$) - reducing the DDE to it's characteristic polynomial - and solve for $\lambda$ via the Lambert-W Function:
\begin{align*}
x'\left( t \right) &= r \cdot x\left( t - d \right) - h \cdot x\left( t \right) \tag{$x\left( t \right) := e^{\lambda \cdot t}$}\\
\lambda \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot t} &= r \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot \left( t - d \right)} - h \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot t}\\
\lambda \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot t} &= r \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot t} \cdot e^{-\lambda \cdot d} - h \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot t} \tag{$\div e^{\lambda \cdot t}$}\\
\lambda &= r \cdot e^{-\lambda \cdot d} - h \tag{$+ h$}\\
\lambda + h &= r \cdot e^{-\lambda \cdot d} \tag{$\cdot \left( d \cdot e^{d \cdot \lambda} \cdot e^{d \cdot h} \right)$}\\
\left( d \cdot \lambda + d \cdot h \right) \cdot e^{d \cdot \lambda + d \cdot h} &= d \cdot r \cdot e^{d \cdot h} \tag{$\operatorname{W}_{k}\left( \cdot \right)$}\\
d \cdot \lambda + d \cdot h &= \operatorname{W}_{k}\left( d \cdot r \cdot e^{d \cdot h} \right) \tag{$- \left( d \cdot h \right)$}\\
d \cdot \lambda &= \operatorname{W}_{k}\left( d \cdot r \cdot e^{d \cdot h} \right) - d \cdot h\tag{$\div d$}\\
\lambda &= \frac{\operatorname{W}_{k}\left( d \cdot r \cdot e^{d \cdot h} \right) - d \cdot h}{d}\\
\end{align*}
where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\operatorname{W}_{k}$ is the [Lambert-W Function](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog2/).

So ($\text{c}_{k}$ and $\text{c}$ are arbitrary complex constants):
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
x\left( t \right) &= \text{c} \cdot e^{\frac{\operatorname{W}_{k}\left( d \cdot r \cdot e^{d \cdot h} \right) - d \cdot h}{d} \cdot t}\\
\end{align*}
$} \tag{1}$$
or
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
x\left( t \right) &= \sum\limits_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}\left[ \text{c}_{k} \cdot e^{\frac{\operatorname{W}_{k}\left( d \cdot r \cdot e^{d \cdot h} \right) - d \cdot h}{d} \cdot t} \right]\\
\end{align*}
$} \tag{2}$$
because there are infinitely many solutions and they are all homogeneous.

Of course, for your scenario not every $k$ and $c$ makes sense, because a population number that is a complex non-real number makes not that much sense. $\text{c}$ could be interpreted as the initial stock / amount of people and the most realistic choice for $k$ would probably be $k = 0$ (often referred to as the main branch) or $\text{c}_{k} = 0 \ne k \wedge \text{c}_{0} := \text{c}$.

---

That would be a plot for $x\left( t \right)$ where $\text{c} := 100$, $r := 1.5$, $d := 20$ and $h = 0.1$ ($t \in \left[ -1,\, 10 \right]$):

[image: x(t) for c=1, r=1.5, d=20, h=0.1 with t in [-1, 10]]

That would be a plot with the parameters for $x_{r}\left( t \right)$ where $r$ goes from $0$ to $2$ in $0.2$ steps and $t \in \left[ -1,\, 20 \right]$:

[image: x(t) with r steping form 0 to 2 in 0.2 steps]

Mathematica-Code:

```
c := 100; d := 20; h := 0.1;
Subscript[x, r_][t_] := c * Exp[((LambertW[0, d * r * Exp[d * h]] - d * h) / d) * t]
Plot[Subscript[x, 1.5][t], {t, -1, 10}]
```

and

```
Plot[{Subscript[x, 0][t], Subscript[x, 0.2][t], Subscript[x, 0.4][t], Subscript[x, 0.6][t], Subscript[x, 0.8][t], Subscript[x, 1][t], Subscript[x, 1,2][t], Subscript[x, 1.4][t], Subscript[x, 1.6][t], Subscript[x, 1.8][t], Subscript[x, 2][t]}, {t, -1, 20}, PlotLegends -> Table[Subscript["x", N[r / 5]], {r, 0, 10}]]
```

---

You should be able to work with that. You could also derive solutions on other ways like seeing that there is the trivial solution $x\left( t \right) = 0$ or using approximation methods.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $x(t)=0\ \forall t\lt d$, and using the Laplace transform, we have

$$
\hat x(s) = \frac{x_0}{(s+h-r e^{-s d})} = \frac{x_0}{s+h}\frac{1}{1-\frac{r e^{-s d}}{(s+h)}}
$$

now assuming $|r e^{-s d}| < |s+h|$ we have

$$
\hat x(s) = \frac{x_0}{s-h}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{r e^{-s d}}{s+h}\right)^k
$$

and

$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\left(\frac{r e^{-s d}}{s+h}\right)^k\right]=\frac{r^k (t-d k)^{k-1} e^{d h k-h t} \theta (t-d k)}{\Gamma (k)}
$$

where $\theta(\cdot)$ is the Heaviside Theta function.

Follows a MATHEMATICA script computing an example for $r = 0.2, h = 0.3, x_0 = 1, d = 2$.

```
n = 5;
parms = {r -> 0.2, h -> 0.3, x0 -> 1, d -> 2};
xt = InverseLaplaceTransform[x0/(s + h) Sum[(r Exp[-s d]/(s + h))^k, {k, 0, n}], s, t];
xt0 = xt /. parms;
Plot[xt0, {t, 0, n d} /. parms, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> All]
```

For $r=0.2, h=0.3$

[image]

For $r=0.2, h = 0.2$

[image]

For $r = 0.2, h = 0.1$

[image]